# How to place a input text in choice option in symfony 3 form

Tags: symfony

How to place a input text in choice option in symfony 3 form

```
->add('structure', 
      EntityType::class, 
      array(
          'class' => 'BlablaBundle:Blabla',
          'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($type) {
              return $er->createQueryBuilder('d') 
                        ->where('d.type = :type')
                        ->setParameter('type', 'structure');
          },
          'choice_label' => array(
              'libelle',
```

//Here it must to be able to add some text
                  'some option' => ('write some text'),
              ),
          )

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: Thank you.I would like to add the possibility to enter text in the choice_label option (ie, I want it to be possible to choose from the dropdown list and enter text if what we are looking for n 'does not exist.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not easily possible with Symfony, as it has to be solved mostly on the client side with JavaScript. You might want to take a look at [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Oh, poor of myself. Thanks anyway. Someone else has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not backend task and symfony is backend framework. Tasks of backend are generate template and retrieve options from database.
So use [Select2](https://select2.org/) or smth like that.